# Small issue with JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, mouseover, mouseout

I have a list of images with overlays. When I mouseover the images, the text and the overlay is suppose to disappear using JQuery. When I hover over an image, the overlay for that specific image disappears, which is right. The problem is the text. When I hover over the image the text disappears for that image and on all the other images. I only want the text and the overlay for that specific image to hide. This seems to be a small issue, since I got the overlay to work right. Thanks in advance friends.

Here is the JQuery:

```
//Hides the screen and text on mouseover
$('.screen').mouseover(function() {
    $('.screen_text').hide();
    $(this).slideUp(400);

});
//Shows the screen and text on mouseout
$('.portfolio img').mouseout(function() {
    $('.screen_text').show();
    $('.screen').slideDown(400);

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without seeing your html mockup, my assumption is that your jquery selector brings back all the text element (because you are doing $('.screen_text') )
I think what you want to do is something like:

```
$('.screen_text',this).hide();
```

which should only bring back the elements that has a class name screen_text in the context of this

Answer (score 2):

The class selector is matching too much.

```
//Hides the screen and text on mouseover
$('.screen').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.screen_text').hide();
    $(this).slideUp(400);

});
//Shows the screen and text on mouseout
$('.portfolio img').mouseout(function() {
    $('.screen_text').show();
    $('.screen').slideDown(400);

});
```

use jQuery's `.find()` to search for `.screen_text` as a descendant of the `.screen` that was hovered on.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are hiding every element which has the class name "screen_text" when you perform `$('.screen_text').hide();`. You should find a better way to select or differentiate them.

There is no way to provide any more support without seeing an example of the DOM. Although there may be a logical error in the execution of this jQuery, there is nothing wrong syntactically.